# aport CBUILDROOT: unable to read database state: No such file directory

Tags: cross-compiling, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I want to build cross compiler for aarcht64 using aports. Im using x86_64 host by the way and below are some steps to reproduce the issue

1. clone https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports
2. export BARCH=aarch64 && CBUILDROOT=~/sysroot-$BARCH ./aports/scripts/bootstrap.sh
   $BARCH

```
>>> bootstrap-aarch64: Building cross-compiler
>>> binutils-aarch64: Building main/binutils-aarch64 2.40-r11 (using abuild 3.11.1-r0) started Wed, 14 Jun 2023 17:59:54 +0700
>>> binutils-aarch64: Checking sanity of /home/hv/libs/aports/main/binutils/APKBUILD...
>>> binutils-aarch64: Analyzing dependencies...
ERROR: Unable to read database state: No such file or directory
ERROR: Failed to open apk database: No such file or directory
>>> ERROR: binutils-aarch64: builddeps failed
>>> binutils-aarch64: Uninstalling dependencies...
ERROR: No such package: .makedepends-binutils-aarch64
Waiting for repository lock
ERROR: Unable to lock database: Bad file descriptor
ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Bad file descriptor
```

My id output is as follows

```
localhost:~/libs$ id
uid=1000(hv) gid=1000(hv) groups=6(disk),10(wheel),300(abuild),1000(hv)

localhost:~/libs$ cat /etc/sudoers.d/wheel
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
localhost:~/libs$ cat /etc/sudoers.d/abuild
%abuild ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

How to solve this, thank you.